# MySQL update with Join to Mongo Aggregate with Lookup

Tags: mongodb

I'm migrating from MySQL to MongoDB. In this process I want to rewrite the following MySQL query:

This query is used to add additional information to the minutes table (adding the program, title, broadcaster and program_id (prid) to the other table)

```
UPDATE etl_staging.sko_minutes minut
JOIN etl_staging.sko_daily AS daily ON
minut.channel = daily.channel AND
(minut.C BETWEEN daily.start_datetime and daily.end_datetime)
set minut.sko_frequency = daily.sko_frequency,
minut.programma = daily.programma,
minut.titel = daily.titel,
minut.omroep = daily.omroep,
minut.prid = daily.prid
WHERE daily.doelgroep = '6+'
AND daily.universe = 'Currency'
```

Now i'm trying to rewrite it to the following... Only i found out that i could not make a join in MongoDB. Was looking at something like this. But that returns an empty minutes array as field to the minutes document.

```
db.sko_minutes.aggregate(
[
{ $lookup: {
from: "sko_daily",
let: { channel: "$channel", start_datetime: "$start_datetime", end_datetime: "$end_datetime",
doelgroep: "$doelgroep", universe: "$universe"},
pipeline: [
{ $match: {
$expr: {
$and: [
{ $eq: ["$$universe", 'Currency']},
{ $eq: ["$$doelgroep", '6+']},
{ $eq: ["$channel", "$$channel"]},
{ $gte: ["$datetime", "$$start_datetime"]},
{ $lte: ["$datetime", "$$end_datetime"]}
]
}
}}
],
as: 'minutes'
}}
]
)
```

Does anybody have an idea what would be the best approach for this problem?

The documents of the sko_minutes looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "5fbb8b85336e42949248fb1b"},
    "abs": 0,
    "channel": "vicetv",
    "date": {"$date": "2020-11-22T00:00:00.000Z"},
    "datetime": {"$date": "2020-11-22T09:20:00.000Z"},
    "hour": 9,
    "kta": 0,
    "minutes": "20",
    "start_time": "09:20:00"
  },
```

And the daily document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id": {"$oid": "5fbb8afb4cab8a4ce5acac5f"},
    "abs": 0,
    "brk": 0,
    "channel": "net5",
    "date": "2020-11-18",
    "doelgroep": "20-34",
    "duration": "47",
    "end_date": "2020-11-18",
    "end_datetime": {"$date": "2020-11-18T01:12:00.000Z"},
    "end_hour": "1",
    "end_minutes": "12",
    "end_time": "25:12:59",
    "hour": "0",
    "kdh": 0,
    "kta": 0,
    "minutes": "12",
    "omroep": "net5",
    "prid": "694949124",
    "programma": "vtwonenverbouwenofverhuizen",
    "sko_frequency": "overige herhaling",
    "start_datetime": {"$date": "2020-11-18T00:12:00.000Z"},
    "start_time": "24:12:00",
    "titel": "Vtwonen verbouwen of verhuizen",
    "universe": "UGK1-6",
    "waardering": 0,
    "webtv_gaas": 0,
    "webtv_nstreams": 0
  },
```

Comment: please post your sample data

Comment: Adding it to the question

Comment: I know they don't match, but there are elements in in that match with the query.

Comment: What should be your desire output?

Comment: I want to add the title, program, omroep and prid from sko_daily to the sko_minutes as additional fields (didn't do the unwind yet, first have the lookup working )
They need to be matched on datetime (between start and datetime) and on the same channel

Comment: What you have tried is totally correct, but when you pass the dtat inside `let`, you need to pass the field in `sko_minutes` for eg: let: `let: { channel: "$channel", start_datetime: "$date", end_datetime: "$datetime" }`. Your args are wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Brings part of **sko_daily** to **sko_minutes**
2. `let` fields are from **sko_minutes**: date, datetime, channel

   - this fields are matched to daily
3. You also require a subset of **sko_daily**, using filters.

Mind you that I tweaked the date fields, and some data, just to make mongoplayground work.

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cb80vFYdXkx)

```
db.sko_minutes.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      /**$$ are from sko_minutes*/
      from: "sko_daily",
      let: {
        "start_datetime": "$date",
        "end_datetime": "$datetime",
        channel: "$channel"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$universe",
                    "Currency"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$doelgroep",
                    "6+"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$channel",
                    "$channel"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $gte: [
                    "$$start_datetime",
                    "$start_datetime"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $lte: [
                    "$$end_datetime",
                    "$end_datetime"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "minutes"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Adding the addfields and using the unset to add the fields to the model (with a out to store it back in the collection)

https://mongoplayground.net/p/3o06hWVr96-

Comment: @Gix `{$addFields:{a:value1, b:value2, c:value3}}` (you can do all in one addFields). You're welcome. Atlas UI and Compass allow you to see the stages in a very beginner friendly way (I use it, it's fantastic). Try it!

Comment: Thank you, any tips on the performance... The minutes has now 36000 records and the daily 219120. Which can even be more

Comment: No worries. There are loads of things, the first could be try to fit an index, to speed up the look up. There are other tips but require a closer look and effort. They vary from reorganizing the databases to indexes, as I said before. You can contact my profile. @Gix